# Почему функция не игнорирует лишние аргументы?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Решил разобраться в функциях и написал следующее:

```
function puts(message){
    console.log(message);
}
puts("Hello,World " + 10 + " and JavaScript!"); // Выдаст Hello,World        
10 and JavaScript!
let a = 10;
let b = 15;
puts (a + b); // 25
```

И вот у меня появился вопрос, разве JS не должен игнорировать лишиние аргументы? Параметр, то один. Объясните пожалуйста!

Comment: Лишние? Вы один аргумент передаёте 

Comment: В смысле один? puts(a + b) - это разве один аргумент?

Comment: У вас вычислится значение `a + b` и в саму функцию будет передан итоговый один аргумент.

Comment: Могу еще добавить, что аргументы разделяются запятой, например `puts (a, b) //10`.

Comment: Все я понял, спасибо! на самом деле, я передаю только один аргумент! если написать puts(3,10 + 10), выдаст только 3! Спасибо!!!

Comment: Да, Степан, просто если писать puts (10+10+10), то получается, что я передаю один аргумент. + является ключом понимания!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вы не совсем успели разобраться в функциях.

Аргументы передаются не через плюс, а через запятую. Т.е. если у нас есть функция `function func(a, b)`, то передавать нужно через запятую: `func(1, 2);`.

`+` в JS обозначает конкатенацию строк(прибавление одной к другой), если это строки, либо сложение чисел, если это числа.

В первой функции вы складываете строку, число, и строку(кстати, лучше числа и строки не складывайте, а то будете удивлены разнообразием результатов. Для перевода числа в строку используйте `String(n)`) и получаете один аргумент: строку `Hello,World 10 and JavaScript!`

Во второй функции вы складываете уже числа, 10 и 25, и опять-таки получаете один аргумент: число 25.

Все просто!

```js
function puts(message){
    console.log(message);
}
puts("Hello,World " + 10 + " and JavaScript!"); // Выдаст Hello,World 10 and JavaScript!
let a = 10;
let b = 15;
puts (a + b, 10); // 25, хотя здесь был передан и второй аргумент. Он был просто проигнорирован.
```

Comment: Да да, спасибо! Уже понял! String(n) взял на заметку!)

Comment: @Vlad Вы также можете [принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), если он вам помог.